# Determine base Ubuntu version

Tags: programming, pantheon-terminal

I'm trying to contribute with Docker's install script by providing auto distribution detection support for elementary OS, so, elementary OS users would be automatically detected when using Docker's official install script.

The script will add an apt repository with the following command:

```
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ${lsb_dist}-${dist_version} ${repo}" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

Where **lsb_dist**=**elementary**, **dist_version**=**freya** and **repo**=**main** in Freya.

After that it'll do apt-get update and install the "docker-engine" package.

Though, Docker apt repository doesn't have entries for elementary OS. I've tested using "ubuntu-trusty" repository and it works just fine in Freya.

So, I want to use Ubuntu repositories to setup Docker for elementary, but I would like to avoid hard coding elementary OS correspondent base Ubuntu versions, if that's possible.

**Question:**

> Is there a file or command which will tell me what's elementary OS' base Ubuntu version, and works in all elementary OS versions?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Take a look at the [node.js repository setup-script](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/deb/setup_0.12) at NodeSource, they are hard-coding all forked distributions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can find the "upstream release" codename using the `-u` flag with `lsb_release` commands. Try it with the following command in Terminal:

```
lsb_release -a -u
```

On Freya, it gives me the following output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Without the `-u` flag, you'll get our info as follows:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary OS
Description:    elementary OS Freya
Release:    0.3
Codename:   freya
```

Comment: Wow! You rock man! That's definitely the best answer! How silly of me not trying all lsb_release --help options. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Credit to Cody Garver. He's just a bit busy to post here himself ;p

Comment: For command line usage it might be good to include `lsb_release -cus`, which gives just the ubuntu codename.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `uname -v` which gives the full Ubuntu based version unlike the other answers. Output is below :

```
#49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 31 15:44:49 UTC 2015
```

If you need to only print the version (like in scripts) you can use`uname -v | cut -c 5- | cut -f1 -d"-"` which prints `14.04.1` on my laptop. Any improvements for the command that only prints the version are welcome

Comment: Any improvements my command that shows only the version

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the Settings/About page.

Answer (score -4):

Every version of elementary OS is built on top of the current Ubuntu's LTS versions. I don't think that there's a command that will tell you that, but here's what was done so far:

- elementary OS Jupiter was built on top of the Ubuntu 10.04 (thanks to PNG for the confirmation).
- elementary OS Luna was built on top of the Ubuntu 12.04.
- elementary OS Freya was built on top of the Ubuntu 14.04.
- elementary OS Loki (note: the code name for this version might be changed) will probably be built on top of the Ubuntu 16.06 version (at the moment, there is no official confirmation nor denial).

Example: [Node.js setup script has alternative distros all hard coded.](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/deb/setup_0.12)

Comment: Jupiter was built on top of the Ubuntu 10.10. About Loki was no official information.

Comment: I was not confirmed, that Jupiter built on the 10.04 :-)